# How to print datagridview results?

Tags: vb.net, printing

How can I get a hardcopy print of the results shown in datagridview?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the `DrawToBitmap` function to save a snapshot of the DataGridView to a bitmap and then print that bitmap.

OR

You will have to write a function that ouputs the DataSource (DataTable, DataSet, etc..) to a text file or directly to a printer. Here are some examples:

[Printing a DataTable to textbox/textfile in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691363/printing-a-datatable-to-textbox-textfile-in-net)

[print gridviews, datagrids, or datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858782/print-gridviews-datagrids-or-datatables)

Answer (score 0):

Since the DataGridVeiw is a reflection of a DataSet you can use
DataSet.WriteXml(XmlFileName.xml)
With this you can export the entire dataSet with all the tables in a XML File. 
YOu can then print this file !

Comment: I have put a print button on the form below datagridview control and I want that when that button is clicked it should prompt a print dialog and then print the results shown in the datagridview control

Answer (score 0):

Printing in Dot net can be either really easy by using the Crystal Report Document, or tedious through the print document.  For a simple table, use Crystal.  You can pass a data adapter directly to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy to output as csv and then print it from Excel.

[export Datagrid to excel asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271485/export-datagrid-to-excel-asp)